# ICMP_ECHO_REPLY32 and IP_OPTION_INFORMATION32

Tags: pointers, vb6, declaration, icmp

In one of my vb6 code i am using [IP_OPTION_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366275%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [ICMP_ECHO_REPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366053%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which i have declared as

```
Private Type IP_OPTION_INFORMATION
   Ttl             As Byte
   Tos             As Byte
   Flags           As Byte
   OptionsSize     As Byte
   OptionsData     As Long
End Type
```

and

```
Public Type icmp_echo_reply
   address         As Long
   Status          As Long
   RoundTripTime   As Long
   DataSize        As Long
   Reserved        As Integer
   ptrData                 As Long
   Options        As IP_OPTION_INFORMATION
   Data            As String * 25
End Type
```

Now i want to use [IP_OPTION_INFORMATION32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540658%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [ICMP_ECHO_REPLY32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) But it has little difference than previous one.So how to declare it in same way?Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since VB6 can only run as a 32 bit process I don't think you need to worry about the differing versions of this structure.  I think it has more to do with pointer sizes on a 64 bit OS.